# Types/IDL isn't generating on building the program

Tags: anchor, anchor-program-idl

Im building the program using `anchor build` with latest version. and it's building successfully also but the target folder is empty

and sometime on building i'm getting this error

```
warning: some crates are on edition 2021 which defaults to `resolver = "2"`, but virtual workspaces default to `resolver = "1"`
note: to keep the current resolver, specify `workspace.resolver = "1"` in the workspace root's manifest
note: to use the edition 2021 resolver, specify `workspace.resolver = "2"` in the workspace root's manifest
error: package `solana-program v1.18.8` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.75.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.72.0-dev
Either upgrade to rustc 1.75.0 or newer, or use
cargo update -p solana-program@1.18.8 --precise ver
where `ver` is the latest version of `solana-program` supporting rustc 1.72.0-dev
```

anchor version is `anchor-cli 0.29.0`

solana version is `solana-cli 1.18.4 (src:356c6a38; feat:3352961542, client:SolanaLabs)`

rustc version is `rustc 1.77.0 (aedd173a2 2024-03-17)`

Answer (score 1):

Probably anchor 0.29.0 is not compatible with solana 1.18.4.

You can probably lock your version to 17 for now:

```
cargo add solana-program@"=1.17"
```